# Bing Aerial metadata in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, bing-maps

I am using Bing Aerial imagery within QGIS through the OpenLayers plugin. How can I find the dates of the images that are within the map canvas?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately using Bing via the OpenLayersPlugin does not supply any meaningful metadata such as acquisition dates.

May I refer you to the following thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/onedrive/en-US/ce592d5b-a14f-4476-b4c5-d9f6ed44c4ad/date-or-acquisition-of-images-in-bing-satellite-images?forum=vemapcontroldev